# PySpark: How to use select in a list comprehension but not truncate columns?

Tags: pyspark

I want to trim the white space from my columns like so:

```
df = df.select( [trim(f"`{col}`").alias(col) for col in string_cols])
```

The problem is, that it is removing all my other columns from my dataframe. How can I do column-specific operations while not throwing away the other columns?

I would like to retain the list comprehension capability.

Comment: Doing it on my phone. Let me know if it doesn't work.  Have you tried?
`df = df.select('*',*[trim(f"`{col}`").alias(col) for col in string_cols])`

Comment: However, if I run a second command, like so, it fails;
`df.select('*', *[when(df[f"`{col}`"] == '', '<missing>').otherwise(df[f"`{col}`"]).alias(col) for col in string_cols] ) `, yielding ambiguous column reference.

Comment: Are you able to post this as a second question now that the first is answered. Someone will help. This needs to be looked into deeper and I am on phone on a small break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it on my phone. Let me know if it doesn't work. Have you tried?

`df = df.select('*',*[trim(f"{col}").alias(col) for col in string_cols])`